# C: Store a pre-compiled chunk of code as char[] and then execute it

Tags: c, binary-data

I was wondering if it's possible to store a chunk of compiled code as a `char[]` and then in some way execute it.

e.g.

```
unsigned char my_code[5] = {124,231,75,123,0};
asm("jal my_code");
```

- Is that possible?
- Does this weird thing have a name, and are there some articles explaining it?

Thanks

Comment: You want to look into lisp, or at least recent C#...

Answer (score 0):

In Standard C the answer is *no, code is not data*.

That said, if the char array contains a complete executable, you could write it to a file and then execute the file (e.g. with `system()`). If it's not a complete executable (only a few instructions) you would somehow turn it into a complete executable.

This was easier in the good old times, when compilers accepted

```
char main[] = { 42, 68, 0xcb, 0xdd, 0, 4, 74, 59 }; /* not a real program */
```

and created an executable program :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Many frameworks use this technique to implement thunks, for instance.  The trick is to make sure the allocated memory block is marked as executable.  On Windows, that means allocating the memory with `VirtualAlloc()` and then granting `PAGE_EXECUTE` rights to it with `VirtualProtect()`.  You can store CPU opcodes in the memory, declare a function pointer that points at the memory, and then call it like any other function.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know hot to do it on Linux?

Comment: Look at `mmap()` and `mprotect()`. [How to allocate executable memory on Linux](http://burnttoys.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-allocate-executable-memory-on.html)